# How to pass props from functional component to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I'm quite new to functional components and I've been on this for hours.
I simply want to pass a prop from a parent functional component to a class child component so that I will use the updated prop (which will be a boolean) to change the display of an element. That's all.

In this scenario, I want to switch the sidenav from opened to closed based on the prop.

Here is the parent component (functional):

```
   let opened = false;

   function openSidenav(){
       opened = !opened;
   }
   const [sidebarOpened, setOpened ] = useState(opened);

   return (
       <Sidebar sidebarOpened={opened} />
   )
```

and the child component (class):

```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(this.props.sidebarOpened !== prevProps){
         this.setState({ sidebar: true});
      }
   }
```

It's just not working, the child component isn't receiving changes, I guess I didn't pass the prop rightly. I know the code just needs correction but I don't know where I'm not getting it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to useState is only used once. You need to set the state in `openSidenav` function to trigger a re-render.

**Parent**

```js
   function openSidenav(){
       setOpened(prev => !prev);
   }
   const [sidebarOpened, setOpened ] = useState(false);

   return (
       <Sidebar sidebarOpened={sidebarOpened} />
   )
```

Also in child component, use `prevProps.sidebarOpened` (not just prevProps).

**Child**

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(this.props.sidebarOpened !== prevProps.sidebarOpened){ //<---- see here
         this.setState({ sidebar: this.props.sidebarOpened});//<---- see here
      }
   }
```

p.s - Also, since you are using props directly in child component, you can consider to not to copy props into state.

Comment: Thank you! I used the prop directly in the render and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In parent,

```
  const [sidebarOpened, setOpened ] = useState(false);

  function openSidenav(){
    setOpened(!sidebarOpened);
  }

  return (
    <Sidebar sidebarOpened={sidebarOpened} />
  )
```

And in child component class directly use `this.props.sidebarOpened` instead of copying over the prop to state. If you intend to edit the value of `sidebarOpened` in the child component, pass `setOpened` to the child component as a prop and use that to edit the value.

Comment: That `setOpened(!opened)` method only worked once (the first time), it didn't work in the subsequent clicks. I guess that's the only difference in your answer and the accepted one. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. the openSidenav() fn must be setOpened(!sidebarOpened). Changed my answer.